# Dealing with 'immediately invoking' functions as object properties

Tags: javascript, function, object, reactjs, state

In a small React project I made, I wanted to initialise an array in `getInitialState` by calling a function. The arguments refer to two other properties in `getInitialState`. This is how I did it:

```
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      numRows: 55,
      numCols: 47,
      arrInit: function(){
        this.grandArr = this.initBlank(this.numRows, this.numCols);
        return this;
      },
    }.arrInit(); //Creates `grandArr` in the `state`
  }
```

(`this.initBlank` is a method in the component that returns an array.)

The way of chaining `arrInit` looks pretty messy. Is there a better/cleaner way to do it?

Comment: The **state** shouldn't have a function in it at all because it doesn't represent any state. It seems `arrInit` is a method of re-initializing some state. Can you describe why you've chosen to structure it this way?

Comment: @Josh David Miller because it's a large array that I can't hard-code

Comment: Leaving aside React issues which I am not competent to comment on, this is a perfectly good way to initialize parts of an object and can even be called a "pattern'.

Comment: @torazaburo I would not expect this to work based on the way that React binds scope.

Comment: @torazaburo thinking further, I'm voting to close this question as _primarily opinion-based_ due to how strongly I disagree with your statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting `this` to refer to both the `state` object AND the component. I would do the setup and then return the object you want:

```
getInitialState() {
  const numRows = 55,
        numCols = 47,
        grandArr = this.initBlank(numRows, numCols);

  return {numRows, numCols, grandArr};
}
```

Comment: Ha. I completed an answer almost identical this within a second or so of this post appearing, so I'll just upvote yours instead. But I still want to note that this seems like a bad way to be using state.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller totally agree; I would probably just capture these as private vars in the component's module. I'm also highly dubious of an implementation in JS which requires a pre-sized _empty_ array, but that is a separate issue entirely.

Comment: @Josh David Miller @Mathletics thanks for the solution! it's for [this Game of Life simulator](http://codepen.io/alanbuchanan/pen/qbXMLP), so the 'empty array' is named poorly - what I mean is, an array full of strings that are literally the word `empty` to mirror 'empty' cells. Because it seems like a bad way to use state, perhaps I should be doing this in `componentDidMount`.